# Custom CGAffineTransformationMake

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview

In my app i would like give a flip animation for an image when a button is clicked.But when i try to do that i can only do four kind of transformation for an image by CGAffinetransformationMake(move,scale,rotate,translate).But I need a flip style transformation.can anyone help me in doing this?

Comment: You can use UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft or UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight animation.

Comment: @mrunal i think  this option is for segue transition.not for an image

Comment: nope this is UIView animation and your UIImageView is already inherited by UIView so you can use this for your image view.

Comment: You can scale in and scale out the imageview along that axis along which you would like to flip.

Comment: can u please provide the code..I m little bit confused

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will surely help. In the button click function, you have to write this code.

```
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.5f];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:yourImageName cache: YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one hope it will help you a little bit.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
    _viewSlidecontainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.0);
} completion:^(BOOL finished){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
        _viewSlidecontainer.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];
}];
```